# Read decisions from Sharepoint 2010 Task in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, object, model, client

I've a problem with the “**client object model** Sharepoint API” and I don't find an answer or person Online that can help me with it.

I try to get all the decisions for a Task and there is no “easy” way to get these. 
At the moment I try to programmatically read the template (“**.xoml**” file) because the decisions are within it (but only the standard decisions and I need standard and **customized** decisions).

I don’t think that that’s the right way to do it. Is there another way to get all the decisions for a Sharepoint 2010 Task?

Comment: I'd suggest posting this on the http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ site. Lots of SharePoint knowledge there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too domain specific, but I guess you need to get a list.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(_URL);
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View/>"; //filter
            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(list); clientContext.Load(listItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    try
                    {
                    foreach (ListItem _item in listItems)
                    {
                       //your code 
                    }
```